# sqlite query with NATURAL JOIN produces extra records

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to query my SQLite database in Python in hopes of returning the result as a Pandas DataFrame. However, something is going wrong in the query that causes an incorrect output with too many records. For example, if I use this query text:

```
query = "SELECT name, season, opponent, ratingA, ratingB  
    FROM players NATURAL JOIN games NATURAL JOIN A_ratings NATURAL JOIN B_ratings  
    WHERE (season="2015-16") AND (home_away="home") AND (tournament="tournX") AND (name="John Doe")"
```

The correct result should be two rows, one for each appearance by that player with those conditions. If you were to print the correct result from a cursor, it would look like this:

```
(u'John Doe', u'2015-16', u'TeamAlpha', 7.5, 8.0)
(u'John Doe', u'2015-16', u'TeamBeta', 6.0, 6.0)
```

*Instead*, I get the ratings for every player on the team for the games that match the conditions, with the name from the query replacing the correct name in the `name` column, like this:

```
(u'John Doe', u'2015-16', u'TeamAlpha', 7.5, 8.0)
(u'John Doe', u'2015-16', u'TeamAlpha', 8.5, 9.0)
(u'John Doe', u'2015-16', u'TeamAlpha', 6.5, 7.0)
(u'John Doe', u'2015-16', u'TeamAlpha', 6.5, 6.0)
(u'John Doe', u'2015-16', u'TeamAlpha', 7.0, 7.0))
(u'John Doe', u'2015-16', u'TeamBeta', 6.0, 6.0)
(u'John Doe', u'2015-16', u'TeamBeta', 8.0, 7.5)
(u'John Doe', u'2015-16', u'TeamBeta', 7.0, 7.0)
(u'John Doe', u'2015-16', u'TeamBeta', 7.5, 8.0)
(u'John Doe', u'2015-16', u'TeamBeta', 6.5, 7.0)
```

It seems there is some kind of multiplication going on between the tables, and I *think* the problem is in the NATURAL JOIN part but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I'm an SQL novice, obviously, but I'm stumped because the query works perfectly if I enter it into my DB Browser for SQLite.

The tables are structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "games" (
`gameID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`season`    TEXT,
`tournament`    TEXT,
`home_away` TEXT,
`opponent`  TEXT,  )

CREATE TABLE "players" (
`playerID`  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`name`  TEXT UNIQUE )

CREATE TABLE "A_ratings" (
`A_ratingID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`playerID`  INTEGER,
`gameID`    INTEGER,
`ratingA`   REAL,
FOREIGN KEY(`playerID`) REFERENCES `players`(`playerID`),
FOREIGN KEY(`gameID`) REFERENCES games(gameID) )

CREATE TABLE "B_ratings" (
`B_ratingID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`playerID`  INTEGER,
`gameID`    INTEGER,
`ratingB`   REAL,
FOREIGN KEY(`playerID`) REFERENCES `players`(`playerID`),
FOREIGN KEY(`gameID`) REFERENCES games(gameID) )
```

Here is the relevant pandas part, but the problem happens even when I just print the cursor results (as above).

```
cnxn = sqlite3.connect(path)
df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest staying away from natural joins and explicitly joining on the columns that you want to join on.  It takes the guesswork out of things.  Especially in a case like this where it's not a clear cut kind of deal.  You've got tables (players and games) that aren't directly related involved, so there isn't a natural join between those two tables without involving the ratings tables.  Depending on the order those joins are done you could end up with a cross join (multiplication) there.  Slightly adding to the complication is that both A_rating and B_rating have their own joins to both the games and players.

Without seeing more of your data, I'm sort of guessing based on the fact that you're getting your desired results in one case from the natural joins, I'd give something like this a try:

```
query = """SELECT 
              name, season, opponent, ratingA, ratingB  
           FROM players
              inner join A_ratings on
                 players.playerID = A_ratings.playerID
              inner join B_ratings on
                 A_ratings.playerID = B_ratings.playerID and A_ratings.gameID = B_ratings.gameID
              inner join games on
                  B_ratings.gameID = games.gameID
           WHERE (season='2015-16') AND 
                 (home_away='home') AND 
                 (tournament='tournX') AND 
                 (name='John Doe')"""
```

Comment: The joins would be easier to write using USING.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I had no idea the order of the joins mattered; I think that's why my attempted solutions were failing me.